# HTML table does not parse correctly in R

Tags: html, xml, r, parsing, web-scraping

I am trying to read in all the tables from the website "http://www.lassen.co.nz/s14tab.php#hrh".  My code to do this looks as follows:

```
library(XML)
library(RCurl)
url<-"http://www.lassen.co.nz/s14tab.php#hrh"
data<-getURL(url)
data<-htmlParse(data)
tables<-readHTMLTable(data)
```

The table indicating "Team Ranking Points" appears to not parse correctly and therefore is shown as NULL.  I have tried using the scrapeR package but had the same result.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idiot (I'm not usually that harsh but that page belongs on myspace or geocities & would be a great "prosecution Exhibit A" for the need to have a license to put HTML on the internet) who made that page decided that [s]he could "make up" new rules for commenting out parts of HTML.

This gem:

```
<TABLE border=0 cellspacing=2 cellpadding=3 /*style="border: 1px solid #000;"*/>
```

appears twice. While the `xml2` C library is good at handling horrible HTML, this tosses it for a bit of a loop. So, we have to deal with the creative commenting first:

```
library(rvest)

pg <- readLines("http://www.lassen.co.nz/s14tab.php")
pg <- gsub("/*style", "style", pg)
pg <- gsub("*/>", ">", pg)

pg <- read_html(paste0(pg, sep="", collapse=""))
html_table(html_nodes(pg, "h2 + table"), fill=TRUE)
```

The same person who can't follow proper HTML coding guidelines seems also to have never heard of the `<div>` tag, so you'll have to do some cleanup of tables 2 & 3.

If they ever change the formatting (unlikely given the ancient processes this thing is built on), the `h2 + table` will need to be updated to better target those three tables.

Comment: Thank you very much.  Your answer worked and provided much amusement to myself and my colleagues.  I was aware that the site as well as its html code was not of the greatest quality but unfortunately, I cannot find the ranking data anywhere else.

Comment: I tried a similar method for the website [http://www.sanzarrugby.com/superrugby/competition-stats/2016-team-ranking/] (without the gsubs) but had no luck, the method only returned an empty list?  Any help on the matter would again be greatly appreciated.  The code I used may be seen below `url <- "http://www.sanzarrugby.com/superrugby/competition-stats/2016-team-ranking/"
rankings <- url %>%
  read_html %>%
  html_nodes("table") %>%
  html_table()`

Comment: @MarkEinhorn if you post a new q and tap me there I can show how to do that. It uses an external JS script that it loads then runs to make the data for the table it builds dynamically.

Comment: Thanks @hrbrmstr, that would be great.